# Проблема в прокрутке Scrolltop до div + 50px (jquery).

Tags: jquery, javascript, прокрутка

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // = Вешаем событие прокрутки к нужному месту
    //   на все ссылки якорь которых начинается на #
    $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top.
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });

});
```

Есть скрипт прокрутки до определенного элемента.
Как прокрутить еще на 50px ниже? Т.е. прокручиваемся до какого-то div`а + 50px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Недавно этот вопрос здесь задавали. Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ey9w/1/) прокрутки до 64px.

В вашем случае будет:

```
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 50.
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, то, что нужно!

Comment: Пожалуйста)

@Alexsandr, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).