# как сделать ссылку переходящую на элемент страницы с помощью scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery

как разместить на странице 4 ссылки и 4 блока высотой 1000px каждый. По клику на ссылку страница должна проскролиться до соответствующего блока. Для решения использовать метод .scrollTop().

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/276227/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-scrolltop-%D0%B4%D0%BE-div-50px-jquery

Answer (score 1):

```js
  var zTop = 1;
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var index = $($(this).attr('href')).index();
  var wh = $(window).height();
  $('section').each(function() {
    var $tgt = $(this);
    var idx = $tgt.index();
    $tgt.removeClass();
    if (index == idx) {
      $tgt.stop(true, true).animate({
        top: 0
      }, 'linear').addClass('active').css({
        'z-index': zTop
      });
    }
    if (index < idx) {
      $tgt.stop(true, true).animate({
        top: wh
      }, 'linear').addClass('below');
    }
    if (index > idx) {
      $tgt.stop(true, true).animate({
        top: -wh
      }, 'linear').addClass('above');
    }
  });
  zTop++;
})

$('a[href="#a"]').trigger('click');

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  var wh = $(window).height();
  $('article, section').height(wh);
  $('.active').css({
    top: 0
  });
  $('.above').css({
    top: -wh
  });
  $('.below').css({
    top: wh
  });
}).trigger('resize');
```

```css
*,
 :before,
 :after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  top: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

#a {
  background: gold;
}

#b {
  background: magenta;
}

#c {
  background: olive;
}

#d {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

h2 {
  font: 300 4em/2 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  font: 300 1em/2 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: .5em;
}

#a a {
  background: #e6c200;
}

#a a:hover {
  background: #f5ce00;
}

#b a {
  background: #e600e5;
}

#b a:hover {
  background: #f500f5;
}

#c a {
  background: #666700;
}

#c a:hover {
  background: #767600;
}

#d a {
  background: #0483ff;
}

#d a:hover {
  background: #148bff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <section id="a">
    <h2>A</h2>
    <a href="#a">Перейти к A</a>
    <a href="#b">Перейти к B</a>
    <a href="#c">Перейти к C</a>
    <a href="#d">Перейти к D</a>
  </section>
  <section id="b">
    <h2>B</h2>
    <a href="#a">Перейти к A</a>
    <a href="#b">Перейти к B</a>
    <a href="#c">Перейти к C</a>
    <a href="#d">Перейти к D</a>
  </section>
  <section id="c">
    <h2>C</h2>
    <a href="#a">Перейти к A</a>
    <a href="#b">Перейти к B</a>
    <a href="#c">Перейти к C</a>
    <a href="#d">Перейти к D</a>
  </section>
  <section id="d">
    <h2>D</h2>
    <a href="#a">Перейти к A</a>
    <a href="#b">Перейти к B</a>
    <a href="#c">Перейти к C</a>
    <a href="#d">Перейти к D</a>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @ЕлизаветаЧепцова Если ответ вам помог, пометьте ответ как правильный (рядом с ответом слева есть галочка). Это простое действие поможет в будующем кому-то со схожей проблемой сразу найти ответ =)